# lessc Option --source-map-rootpath seems not to work

Tags: less, source-maps

I use `lessc` 2.7.3. I generate css files via a makefile and use following paths

- the makefile is in `themes/bodensee`
- the css is generated in `themes/bodensee/css`
- the less files are in `themes/bodensee/less`
- the maps are in the same folder as the css files.

My problem is that css files misses the `themes/bodensee` path, so it raises a file not found on css.map files.

`lessc -s less/wlb.less --clean-css="--s0 --advanced" --source-map-rootpath=themes/bodensee/ --source-map="css/wlb.css.map" css/wlb.css`

The CSS file now contains `sourceMappingURL=css/wlb.css.map``The rootpath does not have any effect.

I also tried a fantasy rootpath and searched for it in the file - it does not appear anywhere. But the option is correct. When I try to missspell the option, LESS drops an error.

What am I missing?

Description of the `--source-map-rootpath` option from [here](http://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options-source-map-options)

> Specifies a rootpath that should be prepended to each of the less file paths inside the sourcemap and also to the path to the map file specified in your output css.
>
> Because the basepath defaults to the directory of the input less file, the rootpath defaults to the path from the sourcemap output file to the base directory of the input less file.
>
> Use this option if for instance you have a css file generated in the root on your web server but have your source less/css/map files in a different folder. So for the option above you might have

Comment: Is it the same w/o the `--clean-css` option? (It's the first thing I'd suspect since it has its own independent sourcemap engine).

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I also found out that `themes/bodensee` is not required as root path. Instead it is required to remove the css directory. Both files are in the same dir and the css points to the css.map with filename only.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was indeed related to the Clean-CSS plugin.

I now call 
`lessc --source-map --clean-css="--s0 --advanced" -s less/wlb.less css/wlb.css` which is working.

There is a [standalone clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css-cli) program, but that does not generate sources for the Less files. It's not clear if the lessc plugin and the standalone tool are the same or different implementations but both use `node`.

The standalone `cleancss` tool removes the source map URL generated by `lessc` be default (did not play around with the dozens of options).

These Node tools develop very fast and manual/tutorials often are outdated. That's why my make file stopped working. Developers of that tools should really consider not to touch working parameters or features and to keep their code compatible.

Comment: *but that does not generate Sources for the LESS files.* Note that in a perfect world if a css file already has a source map (e.g. generated by Less) - a next CSS processor in the chain (e.g. clean-css in this case) should take the existing map into account and also refer/map to the original sources if/where possible. But that in a perfect world (still.. it's important to pay attention to the corresponding tool docs if there're any notes in this regard. E.g. you could try some other CSS minifiers - I heard some are more gentle/fair to the already present sourcemaps).

Comment: I'm happy its working again and can't invest more time into this.